# Query statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

After running this query statement with my database:

```
select * from articles
where content like 'keyword1' or content like 
keyword2' or content like 'keyword3' and date 
between '2012-06-18 00:00:00' and '2012-06-25 23:59:59' 
order by date asc
```

I am able to get back articles sorted based on date with content containing those specified keywords **but not within the date range**. Can anyone let me know what is wrong with this statement and how to correct it?

Thanks!

Comment: Add brace for your statement: where (content like 'keyword1' or content like keyword2' or content like 'keyword3') and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from articles where (content like 'keyword1' or content like 'keyword2' or content like 'keyword3') and (date between '2012-06-18 00:00:00' and '2012-06-25 23:59:59') order by date asc
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the data type of date field in DB is same format which parameter passed in, if date field is date, use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format it to '%Y-%m-%d %h:%M:%s', then compare it. Something like:

```
Where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') between '2012-06-18 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-25 23:59:59'
```

HTH.